# Is it possible to avoid using this terrible file browser in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management, bookmarks

When I'm saving or opening files in certain programs in Windows 7, such as when using Save for Web in Photoshop, or Open Animation in FCheck; I'm only able to use a ridiculously basic and inefficient file browser that looks like this:

[image: in Photoshop]

[image: in FCheck]

This browser doesn't have my Explorer bookmarks, or even an address bar - the only way I can really get to things is by looking through Recent Places.

I've just tolerated it for several years, but at times it can really cut into my productivity, so I was wondering if there is some way to set the default behavior to something different.

Comment: It looks like this is an ongoing issue with [Adobe](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/please_update_outmoded_open_save_menus_in_adobe_products) products

Comment: @Burgi but Fcheck isn't an Adobe product, and I've had this issue in a number of different programs.  Like just now I was using Notepad++, and the save dialog is this type of window as well:
http://i.imgur.com/CDl2MDO.jpg

Comment: I am guessing the developers all use the same excuse "We need to support Windows XP".

Comment: Further evidence is that NotePad++ has an open feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/176) for this change.